# Получаю ошибку связанную с заголовком

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, header

Создаю плагин для wordpress, который при активации будет создавать ячейку 'post_views' в таблице 'wp_posts', а при деактивации удалять её.
Столкнлулся с проблемой:
При активации плагина выводит ошибку:

> The plugin generated 18375 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

А дебагер выводит:

> Level:Notice  Message:Undefined offset: 0

Но таблица создалась.
После деактивации таблица не удаляется.
Прошу найти ошибки в моём коде. Я всего-лишь учусь, прошу строго не судить.

**Index.php**

```
global $wpdb;
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR_CLASSES', IBRYL_DIR . '/includes/classes/' );

require_once (PLUGIN_DIR_CLASSES."PluginController.php");

PluginController::start($wpdb);
```

**class ControllerPlugin.php**

```
require_once ("PluginDefault.php");

class PluginController {

    public static function start($wpdb) {
        register_activation_hook( PLUGIN_DIR, PluginDefault::activate($wpdb) );
        register_deactivation_hook( PLUGIN_DIR, PluginDefault::uninstall($wpdb) );
    }

}
```

class **PluginDefault.php**

```
// в коментах написаны решения, которые искал в интернете, ничего не помогло
class PluginDefault {

    public static function activate($wpdb) {

        $row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'wp_posts' AND column_name = 'post_views'" );

        if ( empty( $row ) ) {
            // SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER';
//            $wpdb->query( "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER';" );
            $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD post_views INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;" );
        }
    }

    public static function deactivate( $wpdb ) {
        $row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'wp_posts' AND column_name = 'post_views'" );

        if ( empty( $row ) ) {
            // SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER';
            $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE wp_posts DROP post_views;" );
        }
    }

    public static function uninstall( $wpdb ) {

        $row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'wp_posts' AND column_name = 'post_views'" );

        if ( empty( $row ) ) {
            // SET SESSION sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER";
//            $wpdb->query( "SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER';" );
            $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}posts DROP post_views ;" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Забыл указать, что sql запросы через phpMyAdmin работают без ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка встречается при ошибки во время активации плагина. Плохая идея добавить колонку в таблицу `wp_posts`, лучше использовать стандартную схему WordPress и хранить post_views в `wp_postmeta`